# What is GoogleAdView and OneRiotLib

Tags: android

I just download sourses of AdWhirl SDK. But it need to some libs for correct build.

Does anyone know where I can find these libs:

- GoogleAdView.jar
- OneRiotLib.jar
- qwandroidsdk.jar

Answer (score 0):

Those should all be optional. Anyways you find them when you log into AdWhirl and go to the publisher sites.

Except qwandroidsdk.jar which was bought by Apple and is now iAd... does not support Android anymore.